# Moshi with Graal has all reflection registered but cannot map fields

Tags: moshi, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to use [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) with GraalVM's native-image, and trying to get the reflection to work.

I have my class:

```java
public class SimpleJson {
  private String message;
  public SimpleJson(String message) { this.message = message; }
  public String getMessage() { return message; }
  public void setMessage(String message) { this.message = message; }
}
```

and code

```java
var simpleJsonJsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(SimpleJson.class);
var simpleJsonString = "{\"message\": \"hello there\"}";
var simpleJsonObj = simpleJsonJsonAdapter.fromJson(simpleJsonString);
var simpleJsonStringBack = simpleJsonJsonAdapter.toJson(simpleJsonObj);
System.out.println("Converting: " + simpleJsonString);
System.out.println("Simple json has message: " + simpleJsonObj.getMessage());
System.out.println("Simple message full json coming back is: " + simpleJsonStringBack);
```

which prints:

```
Converting: {"message": "hello there"}
Simple json has message: null
Simple message full json coming back is: {}
```

and this only works (by avoiding an exception with `SimpleJson is instantiated reflectively but was never registered`) with the following chunk of code, to get everything registered ready for reflection:

```java
@AutomaticFeature
public class RuntimeReflectionRegistrationFeature implements Feature {

  @Override
  public void beforeAnalysis(BeforeAnalysisAccess access) {
        try {
          // Enable the moshi adapters
          var moshiPkgs = "com.squareup.moshi";
          // Standard shared models
          var pkgs = "my.models";

          // Register moshi
          new ClassGraph()
              .enableClassInfo()
              .acceptPackages(moshiPkgs)
              .scan()
              .getSubclasses(JsonAdapter.class.getName())
              .forEach(
                  classInfo -> {
                    System.out.println("Building moshi adapter class info for " + classInfo);
                    registerMoshiAdapter(classInfo.loadClass());
                  });
          // Register everything we've got
          new ClassGraph()
              .enableClassInfo() // Scan classes, methods, fields, annotations
              .acceptPackages(pkgs) // Scan package(s) and subpackages
              .scan()
              .getAllClasses()
              .forEach(
                  classInfo -> {
                    System.out.println("Building class info for " + classInfo);
                    registerGeneralClass(classInfo.loadClass());
                  });
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          throw e;
        }
  }

  private void registerMoshiAdapter(Class<?> classInfo) {
    try {
      RuntimeReflection.register(classInfo);
      Arrays.stream(classInfo.getMethods()).forEach(RuntimeReflection::register);
      ParameterizedType superclass = (ParameterizedType) classInfo.getGenericSuperclass();
      // extends JsonAdapter<X>()
      var valueType = Arrays.stream(superclass.getActualTypeArguments()).findFirst();
      if (valueType.isPresent() && valueType.get() instanceof Class) {
        Arrays.stream(((Class<?>) valueType.get()).getConstructors())
            .forEach(RuntimeReflection::register);
      }
      RuntimeReflection.register(classInfo.getConstructor(Moshi.class));
    } catch (RuntimeException | NoSuchMethodException name) {
      // expected
    }
  }

  private void registerGeneralClass(Class<?> classInfo) {
    try {
      RuntimeReflection.register(classInfo);
      Arrays.stream(classInfo.getDeclaredMethods()).forEach(RuntimeReflection::register);
      Arrays.stream(classInfo.getDeclaredConstructors()).forEach(RuntimeReflection::register);
    } catch (RuntimeException name) {
      // expected
    }
  }
}
```

(inspired by [this issue](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/1179), although I believe that's trying to address `MoshiAdapter`s generated which is a Kotlin only thing).

So, Java doesn't complain about reflection (which it was previously trying to do, hence the error message mentioned), *but* Moshi isn't actually doing anything.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to work around this?

Note, I did try the manual `reflect-config.json` approach with

```json
[
  {
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "queryAllDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "queryAllPublicConstructors": true,
    "name": "my.models.SimpleJson",
    "queryAllDeclaredMethods": true,
    "queryAllPublicMethods": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
  }
}
```

but this resulted in error around `Runtime reflection is not supported for`... - also not good!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple in the end... the registration just needed

```java
Arrays.stream(classInfo.getDeclaredFields()).forEach(RuntimeReflection::register);
```

adding.